# Are 「Aを相手にする」and 「Aの相手をする」the same?

Tags: grammar

> - 大学教授は[常]{つね}にたくさんの学生**を相手に**している。
> - あんなくだらない男は相手にするな。
> - 「うふふ……じゃあ、士道くん**のお相手を**してあげようかしら」

Hi. I’m struggling with the difference between 「Aを相手にする」 and 「Aの相手をする」, for they seem to have the same meaning. For example, it seems we can use 「Aを相手にする」 and 「Aの相手をする」 interchangeably in the above sentences.

> - 大学教授は[常]{つね}にたくさんの学生の相手をしている。
> - あんなくだらない男の相手をするな。
> - 「うふふ……じゃあ、士道くんをお相手にしてあげようかしら」

Or is there really any difference between 「Aを相手にする」 and 「Aの相手をする」?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they’re different, although there is some overlap in the meaning

> 相手にする deal with; take someone on (in a match or competition)
>
> 相手にしない refuse to deal with; ignore;spurn
>
> 相手をする keep smb. company; entertain one’s guests

(from 研究社新和英中辞典)